# Pystray icon inappropriate behavior with Tkinter window withdraw

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter, pystray

**Description:**
So I am using customtkinter library instead of tkinter, the issue I am facing is that I want my tkinter app to be withdrawn when closed if the minimize window checkbox is checked in settings of the app. The first time I perform this action the app withdraws as well as pystray icon appears in the taskbar, when I open the window again using the "open app" button the app deiconifies but when I try the same method second time I get an error.

**Source Code:**
Below is my code through which I am implementing this operation

```
def save_checkbox_state(state):
    with open('.\\_internal\\src\\checkbox_state.pickle', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(state, file)

def read_checkbox_state():
    try:
        with open('.\\_internal\\src\\checkbox_state.pickle', 'rb') as file:
            state = pickle.load(file)
            # Modify this section according to your UI framework
            if state == 'on':
                checkbox.select()
                check_var.set('on')
            else:
                checkbox.deselect()
                check_var.set('off')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    
def app_destroy():
    icon.stop()
    app.destroy()

def open_app():
    icon.stop()
    app.after(0,app.deiconify())
    
image = Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\ico.png")
menu=pystray.Menu(pystray.MenuItem("Open enigma:guard",open_app),pystray.MenuItem("Exit", app_destroy))
icon = pystray.Icon('enigma:guard', image, "My system tray icon", menu)

def destroy_window():
    checkbox_state = check_var.get()
    save_checkbox_state(checkbox_state)
    if checkbox_state == 'on':
        app.withdraw()
        
        icon.run()
    else:
        app.destroy()
        icon.stop()


settings_minimize_frame = customtkinter.CTkLabel(settings_frame_win,text="",image=settings_minimize)
settings_minimize_frame.place(x=420,y=121)

check_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(settings_minimize_frame, text="", variable=check_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off",width=30,height=35,checkbox_height=35,checkbox_width=35,border_color="#1FFFA9",bg_color="#000000")
checkbox.place(x=1078,y=33)

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroy_window)
```

**Error:**
Below is the error I am facing when I close the window and it minimizes and I reopen it the second time:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[hidden]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python_encryptor_decryptor\project2\enigma_guard.py", line 1228, in destroy_window
    icon.run()
  File "C:\Users\[hidden]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_base.py", line 212, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Users\[hidden]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 120, in _run
    self._hwnd = self._create_window(self._atom)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\[hidden]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_win32.py", line 244, in _create_window
    hwnd = win32.CreateWindowEx(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\[hidden]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pystray\_util\win32.py", line 204, in _err
    raise ctypes.WinError()
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid.
```

**Already tried:**
I tried to destroy the window instead of withdrawing it but that makes the useability a lot awkward since I am giving a splash screen at startup.

Comment: Try looking into the first error as that might be indirectly causing the second one. The first error is telling you that for some reason one of the `tkinter` callbacks is a `str`ing instead of a function. The second error is telling you that `pystray` is trying to open a new window but can't for some reason.

Comment: Also `app.after(0,app.deiconify())` should actually be either `app.after(0,app.deiconify)` or `app.deiconify()` but I don't think this is causing the problem

Comment: @TheLizzard the function calling isn't the problem, I already knew it but I double checked the problem and it's still there.

Comment: You need to create new instance of `pystray.Icon` after calling `.stop()` on current instance.

Comment: @TheLizzard btw sorry, I mentioned a previous error too in my error code embed I removed it though and that's not the issue I am just getting the window edit.

Comment: @acw1668 I am gonna try that I'll let you know if that works, K?

Comment: @acw1668 so I tried mentioning the icon variable before each time I used icon.run() but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** So after a lots of debugging I finally found the issue, the code of the pystray works in a loop in a certain way that it works only once. To repeat the loop everytime I created the function inside the destroy_window function itself so everytime the window closed the function runs creating the icon from pystray from scratch.

**Source Code:**

```
def save_checkbox_state(state):
    with open('.\\_internal\\src\\checkbox_state.pickle', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(state, file)

def read_checkbox_state():
    try:
        with open('.\\_internal\\src\\checkbox_state.pickle', 'rb') as file:
            state = pickle.load(file)
            if state == 'on':
                checkbox.select()
                check_var.set('on')
            else:
                checkbox.deselect()
                check_var.set('off')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    
def destroy_window():
    checkbox_state = check_var.get()
    save_checkbox_state(checkbox_state)
    if checkbox_state == 'on':
        app.withdraw()

        def open_app():
            icon.stop()
            app.after(0,app.deiconify)

        def app_destroy():
            icon.stop()
            app.destroy()

        menu=pystray.Menu(pystray.MenuItem("Open enigma:guard",open_app),pystray.MenuItem("Exit", app_destroy))
        image = Image.open(".\\_internal\\assets\\ico.png")
        icon = pystray.Icon('enigma:guard', image, "My system tray icon", menu)
        icon.run()

    else:
        app.destroy()
        icon.stop()

settings_minimize_frame = customtkinter.CTkLabel(settings_frame_win,text="",image=settings_minimize)
settings_minimize_frame.place(x=420,y=121)

check_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
checkbox = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(settings_minimize_frame, text="", variable=check_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off",width=30,height=35,checkbox_height=35,checkbox_width=35,border_color="#1FFFA9",bg_color="#000000")
checkbox.place(x=1078,y=33)

app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroy_window)
```